# Convention of silent vs. verbose in R functions

Tags: r

I've seen both the `silent` and `verbose` arguments as ways to specify whether R functions should print output. For example, `silent` appears in [`try`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/try.html) while verbose appears in [`install.packages`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/install.packages.html). Defaults can be equivalent, i.e. `function(..., silent=T)` ~ `function(..., verbose=F)`.

At first glance these seem to generally perform the same function. Is there a standard convention on when to use one over the other? I'm wondering for writing my own functions and packages.

Comment: Don't forget `quiet` too :-) http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/knitr/docs/knit

Comment: 100% consistency in function argument naming conventions in R? Even among the base packages? Hahahahahahaha.....!

Comment: ...seriously, though, I don't think there is a strong convention. Use the one that makes the most sense to you.

Comment: I prefer `quiet` because it makes me feel powerful, as if though I'm saying to the function "quiet down you!"  `silent` is a bit harsh, as in "Silence village idiot!"  On the other hand `verbose` is too hippie positive for my taste, as in "I'd prefer you not be so verbose right now function but do what you feel is right."

Comment: It seems to me that `quiet` to suppress messages and `silent` to suppress messages and warnings would be a reasonable convention

Answer (score 0):

*OpenSuSE* archival explanation:
From SuSE 8.2 on, you can press <kbd>F2</kbd> before launching the boot process to select whether the boot messages should be displayed:

- on a colored splash screen ("verbose");
- on a black console ("native");
- or be skipped ("silent").

The default setting is "silent" and you want to change it.
**Source**: https://tr.opensuse.org/SDB:Changing_the_Splash_Screen%27s_Default_Settings

Comment: Welcome at SO! Please note that the question has an "R" tag (= related to the programming language R) and your answer refers to Open SuSE. Nevertheless it is interesting to look beyond one's own nose